# Why can I use 3 dimensions to subset a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Recently, I'm learning R's dataframe. You know that we can subset R's data.frame like below:

```
foo  <- data.frame(mpg[1:5, ])
foo[1:2,3:4]
>#       displ  year
>#  1      1.8  1999
>#  2      1.8  1999
```

But I happened to add a third dimensions in [ ] like the code below and excuted it,

```
foo[1:2, 3:4, 5]
>#       displ  year
>#  1      1.8  1999
>#  2      1.8  1999
```

I thought it would throw an exception. **However, everything goes well.**

In my understanding, R's data.frame is a kind of two-dimensional table. So why can I use 3 dimensions to subset a dataframe in R? What happened behind these code? What is the underlying principle?
And when I tried to subset the dataframe use the 4th dimension or more like `foo[1:2, 3:4, 5, 6]`, this time it will pop an error `Error in  [.data.frame  (foo, 1:2, 3:4, 5, 6): unused argument (6)`. I'm completely confused now.

Any help is welcome, appreciate it.

Comment: The third argument is for "drop". There is no fourth argument. Try `foo[1:2, 3:4, 5, drop=6]` and R will say [5] is unused.

Comment: Now I think I just don't understand what function I called by using [ ]. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just note that data frames have two dimensions. If you include a third argument to `[]`, named or not, then R will assume that this is the "drop" argument. If you include a fourth argument, named or not, then R will give an error because there is no fourth argument. Simple!

Comment: The function you typed was `[]` but since the object it applied to was a data frame, "foo", R called the `[data.frame` function. This function has only three arguments, `i`, `j` and `drop`. These can be named or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a `data.frame`, S3 dispatch means you are using `[.data.frame`; you can see its arguments with `formals` or `args`:

```
args(`[.data.frame`)
# function (x, i, j, drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 1) 

formals(`[.data.frame`)
# $x
# $i
# $j
# $drop
# if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 1
```

You can consult `?"[.data.frame"` for more details about the meaning of these arguments.

As to why it didn't fail, this is likely owing to lazy evaluation; you might check Hadley's book, or jut search around for "lazy evaluation R" for some more resources

- http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/about-lazy-evaluation/

Comment: The third argument doesn't cause an error because `as.logical(5)` is equivalent to `drop=TRUE`

Comment: @Brian indeed you're correct! I'll leave the links to lazy eval since they are important to be exposed to